# Setting up a relation to another class with DbContext (Entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

My context is this: [Using Razor to create a form for hierarchy of domain models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012121/using-razor-to-create-a-form-for-hierarchy-of-domain-models)

I have a class `Project` and a table in a database called `Projects`.

In this table there is a column called `AddressID`... It relates to another Address table.

An Address consists of a few properties... Address1, Address2, City, Country, State. I have mapped these in an `Address` class so that it correlates to the address table.

The Project is thereby related to the Address table through the AddressID... an integer.

In my Project class, for some reason I thought I may be able to do this:

```
class Project
{
    Address Address;
}
```

I then realised that when I go fetch a Project - an `int` column AddressID (The Projects relationship column) - it will try to map to the Address property of Project and say something like "Incompatible types"... Do I need to have something more like this?

```
class Project
{
    int AddressID {get;set;}

    Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

Then when I call some projects from my project repository, I go map the entirety of the Address to the Address property by using the AddressID (mapped from the db) to supply enough information to find the Address in the Db?

What's the usual technique for such things?

Comment: why don't you generate model from database ?

Comment: Database has already been created by the database guys... I thought this might be the safest bet? It's also already being used by another application.

Comment: If that other project is a .NET EF project as well you can make a reference to that project (the DLL files) and use the models.

Comment: If the database already exists then save yourself hassle and use EntityFramework in the Database-First approach! You can tweak the model that is generated, and rename/remodel entities as you see fit but that first generated model will be totally usable. If the primary and foreign keys have been defined correctly in db then your model will correctly have a navigation property from `Project` to `Address`.

Comment: Interesting, i'll read up about all of this database first... as for the other project in .net... no, it's in Lotus Scrotes(Notes) <vomits>... It accesses the same db.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class Project
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressID")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    // Your address properties here...
}
```

Now when you get your entities from the database, you can explicitly include the `Address` of a `Project` using the `.Include()` extension method from `System.Data.Entity`, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjectsAndAddresses()
{
    return myDbContext.Projects.Include(x => x.Address);
}
```

If you have lazy loading enabled and do not dispose of your `DbContext` instance, EF will try to load the foreign entity when you try to access it (in which case you don't need to use the `Include()` method).